# File chooser don't work in main method

Tags: java

I building the save dialog on my notepad and it's a problem because i have the method which save file in the another class and when i using in the  public static void main(String[] args)  its doing  nothing `

```
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("edytor_tekstu");
    frame.setContentPane(new edytor_tekstowy2().panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    edytor_tekstowy2 edytor = new edytor_tekstowy2();
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
            if (czy_zapisany == false) {
                Object[] options = {"YES",
                        "NO", "YES, BUT SAVE"};
                int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                        "Exit, but file is not save ???",
                        "YOU DONT SAVE SAVED FILE",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                        null,
                        options,
                        options[0]);
                if (czy_zapisany == false) {
                    if ("NO".equals(n)) {

                    } else if (("YES".equals(n))) {
                        edytor.saveas();
                    } else if (("YES, BUT SAVE".equals(n))) {
                        edytor.saveas();

                    }
                } else {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The `edytor_tekstowy2` that you're calling `saveas()` on is not added to the frame.

Because here:

```
frame.setContentPane(new edytor_tekstowy2().panel);
```

You're creating a new instance of `edytor_tekstowy2` and you don't keep a reference to it.

You actually create a new object:

```
edytor_tekstowy2 edytor = new edytor_tekstowy2();
```

Which you keep a reference to and use in the `windowClosing` method.

You'll need to change

```
frame.setContentPane(new edytor_tekstowy2().panel);
```

To

```
frame.setContentPane(edytor.panel);
```

Also, `n` is an `int`. All your conditions where you compare `n` to a `String` (`"NO".equals(n)`, `"YES".equals(n)`, etc.) will be `false` because of that.

You'll need to use something like `"NO".equals(options[n])` or `n == 0`.

Comment: nothing when i clicked the  "YES" button  nothing happends

Comment: @thenewproblem Have you changed the code as I've mentioned in my answer ?